# $(2^a -1)(2^b -1)=2^{2^c}+1$ has no nonnegative integer solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, computer-science, parity

$(2^a -1)(2^b -1)=2^{2^c}+1$ is not possible for a,b,c nonnegative integers.

Any solutions using parity

Approach:
$(2^a -1)(2^b -1)=2^{2^c}+1\Rightarrow$

$2^{a+b}-2^a-2^b=2^{2^c}\Rightarrow$

Comment: Suppose on the contrary that there are nonnegative integer solutions $a,b,c$. Maybe you should see if this holds: $2^{gcd\left(a,b\right)}-1$ divides $\left(2^{a}-1\right)\left(2^{b}-1\right)$. I think you should use congruences.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that there was a solution and wlog that $a<b$. Divide by $2^a$, then you have

$2^b-1-2^{b-a}=2^{2^c-a}$

The left side is clearly odd, the right side is even or a fraction if $2^c<a$. Therefore, there cannot exist such a solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

The binary expansion of natural numbers is unique. Assume there exists a solution and use that to obtain two distinct binary expansions of the same number thus yielding a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks. This is a non-trivial fact so I would need to prove it, if given in a test. Any other hint? This is a "Use parity" exercise.

Comment: Why? $2(2^{a+b-1}-2^{a-1}-2^{b-1})=2(2^{2^c-1})$ after showing it fails for a=b=c=0 and a=b=c=1

Comment: Yea I take that back, didn't look closely. Comment deleted.

Comment: do you have any solution in mind?

Comment: I find the approach with binary expansion satisfying enough. Uniqueness of binary expansion is an extremely elementary result, the uniqueness of the *decimal* expansion lies at the very heart of our arithmetic intuition.

Comment: I meant any other solution. It is not an elementary proof. http://math.stanford.edu/~ksound/Math171S10/MidtermSols.pdf

Comment: How is that not elementary? There is virtually nothing used except pure logic and arithmetic.

Comment: From your link: "if $n = \displaystyle \sum_{j = 0}^k a_j 2^j$ with $a_k = 1$ and $a_j \in \{0, 1\}$, then we have $2^k \leq n \leq 2^k + 2^{k-1} + \dots + 1 = 2^{k+1} - 1$. Thus $k$ is uniquely determined as the largest power of $2$ not exceeding $n$. The uniqueness of the binary expansion of $n - 2^k$ is also unique using the induction hypothesis and thus the binary expansion is unique" -- how is that not elementary? Bases are made so we can only have one representation for every number. Can $77$ be written in more than one way in decimal? I answered my own question by writing it as "77."

Comment: you have to prove existence too.

Comment: @TKM We are not talking about alien numbers, it's just the same as with base $10$...